# PHP Custom 'MVC': Including 'modules' that contain HTML/CSS/JS the right way

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, templating

I have created my custom PHP 'MVC', if you'd call it that, with a structure that treats pages and certain components as 'modules', by storing them in their own folders that include any code related to the 'modules'. Modules look roughly like this:

```
├── popup/
│   ├── popup.css
│   ├── popup.js
│   └── popup.php
└── home/
    ├── index.php
    ├── css
    │   └── style.css
    ├── js
    │   └── script.js
    └── html
        └── layout.php
```

I find this structure much better to work with, and apparently this guy does as well: [Lay Out Your Code Like You'd Lay Out Your House](https://dev.to/_bigblind/lay-out-your-code-like-youd-lay-out-your-house-hco)

The **popup** is a component that can be added to a view, and **home** is a view (*I'm not storing them in the same location, but have simplified the structure just for the sake of this example*).

I want to be able to easily include the **popup** component in the views that it's used. What I'm doing now is including the CSS, JS and HTML separately, like this:

```
on home/css/style.css:
@import "../../popup/popup.css"

on home/js/script.js:
// @codekit-prepend '../../popup/popup.js';

on home/html/layout.php:
include '../../popup/popup.php';
```

The perfect case scenario in my head is to be able to include the **popup** component with a one liner on each view, similar to including a PHP library. Is there a right way to do this?

I previously rendered the **popup**'s CSS and JS inside the html document using *link* and *script*, so I could include the complete module by just including *popup.php*. This increases the number of external CSS and JS files the document has to load. The legend also has it that it's better to include a single large CSS/JS file than to include many small ones. Is this still valid in 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: "legend has it": bundling and minification will reduce the overhead of multiple requests and the overall byte count.

The other part of your question - the "how do I simplify module usage" - is probably going to involve beefing up your MVC code base. What you might want to be doing is that each module has a core file or routine that will be called by your base code .. include_me.php or class::bootstrap(&$theApp) .. your mileage may vary - then inside the parts where CSS and JS is meant to be included you walk through theApp-arrays like $pageCSS, $headJS and $bodyJS and in the appropriate places include all the files that the include_me/bootstrap routines placed into those arrays.